# Return value of "count" property in JSON object

Tags: c#, vb.net, facebook-graph-api

I have a json object from the facebook api

```
"comments": {
        "count": 2
     },
 "updated_time": "2012-05-24T02:46:36+0000"
```

The entire json object is a dynamic object.

I can easily read the value of the updated_time with:

```
 post.updated_time
```

However this returns the count of items in the collection, not the value of the "count" property in the json object.

```
 post.comments.count
```

Is it possible to get the value of post.comments.count without it using the "count" keyword?

I should note that the JSON is much larger than this. If there are actually comments there is another collection of the actual comments so something like post.count(0) would not work in that case.

[image: Watch Window]

Comment: Did you try post.comments.length?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the value of the count property of the JSON example in your question, you would have to access it like so:

```
post.comments.count
```

Since the "count" property is part of an object that is the value of the "comments" property

An alternative way to access the object is:

```
post["comments"]["count"]
```

But I think the first one is more readable (The second one can be useful in some situations)

Comment: I added more information above along with a screenshot of the watch window. I did try your suggestion to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I guess `count` is reserved word in C#.</strike>

`count` is not reserved in C#. But still you can,

Try this,

```
post.comments.@count
```